# How to resize a picture copied from Excel to Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, resize

This is my VBA to copy a picture from Excel to Outlook. It comes out very blurry and it is very small.

How can I resize it?

```vb
    Dim MailSelection As Object
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email Sheet").Select
    Sheets("Email Sheet").Range("A1:AP60").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailSelection = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With MailSelection
        .To = "TPrs@t-mobile.com; TPes@T.com; TPACam@t.com; Ni.Joh@T.com; Taam@T.com;"
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "TPACCResourcePlanningTeam@t-mobile.com"
        .Subject = "Hourly Handle Time and Shrinkage"
        .HTMLBody = "<html><center><FONT COLOR=""FFFFFF"">.</FONT></center> 
</html>"
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
        .Attachments.Add ("N:\MACRO AND REPORTS\OFFICIAL REPORTS\Same Day CRT & 
Shrinkage Tampa TEST.xlsb")
        .Display
'Wait for email to be created
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
'Paste range at bottom of email
        SendKeys "^({v})", True
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        SendKeys "{END}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}", True
    End With
    'Get excel range to copy into email as picture

End Sub
```